# How to install code-owners plugin in gerrit?

Tags: plugins, gerrit, github-codeowners

I have downloaded this plugin using " wget https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/job/plugin-code-owners-bazel-stable-3.4/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bazel-bin/plugins/code-owners/code-owners.jar " and move the code-owners.jar into the xxx/plugins, and then restart my gerrit, but it doesn't work and I can't find this plugin in the Plugins List whose path is /admin/plugins.
Hope for help, thanks.

I use gerrit-2.14.16 and jdk8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

Have you followed all the instructions in the "Admin Guide" of the [code-owners plugin documentation](https://android-review.googlesource.com/plugins/code-owners/Documentation/index.html)?

Then:

You have used code-owners plugin target to Gerrit 3.4, is this your Gerrit version? Probably it will not work in a different Gerrit version especially if it's an old one. Take a look at the GERRIT-SITE/logs/error_log file for errors in the plugin initiating.

Comment: yes, I have setup my gerrit and All-Projetcs and my own project following the setup guide https://android-review.googlesource.com/plugins/code-owners/Documentation/setup-guide.html before I install the plugin. And I wonder can the reason be my gerrit version is too old ? I use gerrit-2.14.16 and jdk8. Thanks for Help!

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It's really helpful! And may I ask your to answer another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598425/how-to-install-gerrit-3-3-0-using-jdk8

Comment: Yes. Could you accept the answer?